# .where statement to filter posts by date causing large number of database queries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

My first StackOverflow question, so pardon if it's a little rough around the edges. I recently began my first engineering job and have inherited some legacy **Ruby on Rails** code to work through.

**My goal:**

- is to fetch posts (this is a model, though with no association to user) belonging to a user, as seen below. The posts should be filtered to only include an `end_date` that is `null`or in the future

**The problem:**

The ActiveRecord query `@valid_posts ||= Posts.for_user(user).where('end_date > ? OR end_date IS?', Time.now.in_time_zone, nil).pluck(post_set_id)` (some further context below)

generates ~15 calls to my database per user per second when testing with Postman, causing significant memory spikes, notably with increased # of posts. I would only expect (not sure about this) 2 at most (one to fetch posts for the user, a second to fetch posts that match the date constraint).

- **In absence of the `.where('end_date > ? OR end_date IS?', Time.now.in_time_zone, nil)`, there are no memory issues whatsoever.** My question essentially, is why does this particular line cause so many queries to the database (which seems to be the cause of memory spikes), and what would be an improved implementation?

**My reasoning thus far:**

- My initial suspicion was that I was making an N+1 query, though I no longer believe this to be the case (compared `.select` with `.where` in the query, no significant changes. A third option would possibly be to use `.includes`, though there is no association between a user and a post, and I do not believe that it would be feasible to generate one, as to my level of understanding, users are a function of an organization, not their own model.
- My second thought is that because I am using a date that is precise to the millisecond, the time is ever changing, and therefore the updated time runs against the `posts` table every time there is a change in time (in this case every millisecond). Would it be possible to capture the current time in a variable and then pass this to the `.where` statement, rather than with a varying time, as is currently implemented? This would ultimately cause a sort of caching mechanism if I am not mistaken.
- My third thought was to add an index to `end_date` on the posts table for quicker lookup, though in itself, I do not believe this to provide a solution.

**Some basic context:**

While there are many files working together, I have tried to overly-simplify them to essentially reflect the information that I believe is necessary to understand the issue at hand. If there is no identifiable cause for this issue, then perhaps I need to dig into other areas of code.

`for_user` is a user scope defined below:

- `user_scope`

```
module UserScopable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
...

scope(:for_user, 
  lambda { |poster|
    for_user_scope(
      { user_id: poster.user_id, organization_id: poster.organization_id}
    )
})
scope(:for_user_scope, lambda { |hash|
  where(user_id: hash.fetch(:user_id), organization_id: hash.fetch(:organization_id))
})
```

`@valid_posts` is contained within a module, `PostSetFilter` and called in the `user` controller:

- `users_controller`

```
def post_ids
   post_pools = PostSetFilter.new(user: user)
   render json: {PostPools: post_pools}
end
```

Ultimately, there's a lot that I do not know, and it seems like many approaches, so not entirely sure how to proceed. Any guidance about how to reduce the number of queries, and any reasoning as to why would be greatly appreciated.

I am happy to provide further context if needed, though everything points to the aforementioned line as being the culprit.. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does `for_user_scope` do?

Comment: Apologies, I edited the original post to reflect for_user_scope. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see anything in there that would hit the database so many times. Are you sure that query is the cause? Also, what does `Posts.for_user(user).where('end_date > ? OR end_date IS?', Time.now.in_time_zone, nil).to_sql` have to say?

Comment: That scope has very smelly smell to it. This should almost guaranteed be handled with an assocation since scopes can't be eager loaded. If I had to venture a guess the original author did something very *clever* instead of creating a join table like a sane person.